# XSLT - parse 1 element on XML that has 2 elements same name

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt

I'm trying to get a value from an element, problem is that the element can appear several times and is not nested within another element that I need to compare.

Here's part of my XML:

```
<sim_pur_pric>
  <spp_code>001</spp_code> 
  <spp_price>213.0136</spp_price> 
  <spp_unit>ea</spp_unit> 
  <spp_curr>USD</spp_curr> 
  <spp_cost_comp>001</spp_cost_comp> 
  </sim_pur_pric>
<sim_pur_pric>
  <spp_code>005</spp_code> 
  <spp_price>212.498553</spp_price> 
  <spp_unit>ea</spp_unit> 
  <spp_curr>USD</spp_curr> 
  <spp_cost_comp>001</spp_cost_comp> 
  </sim_pur_pric>
  <storage_conditions /> 
  <cust_po />
```

What I need to get is the value of spp_price but only for spp_code equal to 001, however as you can see the element sim_pur_pric appears twice for different spp_code.

This is what I have on my xsl (part of it):

```
<xsl:template match="sim_pur_pric">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="spp_code"='001'">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(spp_price) != 0">
          <xsl:value-of select='spp_price'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>0|</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>0|</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

However it does not work... :(  does any of you experimented guys know how can I get the value I want? I appreciate your time and help

One last thing, it has to be XSL Version 1.0 since I'm parsing on Unix with xsltproc

Comment: Hi, what is the output you are getting, and what do you expect? There looks to be a stray quote (directly after spp_code) in the test attribute on the first `<xsl:when>`, maybe this is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you have can only be fixed from outside of your "sim_pur_pric" template.  Currently, it applies to both "sim_pur_pric" nodes.  You need XPath to test for the existence of a valid "sim_pur_pric" node.

```
<xsl:apply-template match="sim_pur_pric">
```

Is replaced with something like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="sim_pur_price[spp_code='001' and string-length(spp_price) != 0]">
     <xsl:value-of select="sim_pur_price[spp_code='001']"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>0|</xsl:text>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It did help so much actually!! However, how can I only pull up one node instead of the 5 of them? My txt shows 001213.0136eaUSD001 for that field. I'm sorry, I'm really so newbie to xsl.

Comment: nevermind!! I figured it out!! :)
This did the trick:
`<xsl:value-of select="sim_pur_pric[spp_code='001']/spp_price"/>`